# Customize the style of Markdown Headings in VS Code Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

In VS Code Jupyter Notebooks, it is really hard to distinguish between a first level header and a second level header, which makes it hard and confusing to navigate in a long document. I have very poor knowledge of CSS and I couldn't find a way to customize the font size and color of headings.

Please note I'm referring to rendered markdown (in preview).

Thank you for your help.